# How to display the month ahead from today's date - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to find a function to display to get a month's date from today. So if today `is 7 may`, the next month I want to get is `7 June`.

I tried using this code

`Carbon::now() + 30` but it doesn't help with what I want to achieve.

PS: new to Laravel and sorry about my bad English

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `addMonth()`:

```
Carbon::now()->addMonth();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
$dt = Carbon::now();  // This will assign current date into $dt
echo $dt->addMonth(); // this will print next month's date.
```

Comment: Hey @trump's son. Did you try any of the answers posted here?

Answer (score 1):

also if you want add how many months if you want.

```
$dt = Carbon::now();
$dt->addMonths(3); //After 3 months
$dt->subMonth(3);  //Before 3 months
```

All tips are here [carbon.nesbot.com/docs/](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)